# ¿Como solucionar el error "ContextSwitchDeadlock"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Abrí el visual studio normalmente, y cuando quiero ejecutar mi programa, al cabo de 1 minuto me lanza un `"ContextSwitchDeadlock"` y el programa se queda en ejecución pero nunca muestra nada. No se a que se puede deber el error porque no toque nada, ni siquiera cambie algo en mi propio código que generara ese error, simplemente me lo empezó a mostrar y por eso no lo puedo solucionar, al no saber el origen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Este es el mensaje completo:**

> Asistente para la depuración administrada 'ContextSwitchDeadlock': 'El
>   CLR no ha podido realizar la transición del contexto COM 0xfc74c0 al
>   contexto COM 0xfc7408 durante 60 segundos. Es probable que el
>   subproceso que contiene el contexto o apartamento de destino esté en
>   espera sin proporcionar mensajes o que procese una operación de
>   ejecución muy larga que no proporcione mensajes Windows. Normalmente,
>   esta situación tiene un impacto negativo en el rendimiento y puede
>   hacer que la aplicación no responda o que acumule continuamente el uso
>   de la memoria. Para evitar este problema, todos los subprocesos de
>   contenedores uniproceso (STA) deberían utilizar primitivos de espera
>   que proporcionen mensajes (como CoWaitForMultipleHandles) y
>   proporcionar mensajes regularmente durante operaciones de ejecución
>   largas.'

Y si le doy a continuar, al minuto me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y se detiene la ejecucion

Comment: tiene un problema con el depurador que impide que el mensaje se transmita si está pasando por el código.

Comment: Te paso este enlace que dice porqué sale ese mensaje y cómo desactivarlo: https://cesar.themudo.com/2015/03/desactivar-contextswitchdeadlock/

Comment: Vi que habia gente que mostraba como desactivarlo en el StackOverflow (ingles) pero los que recomendaban eso eran repudiados porque decian que nunca se debe ignorar el error, ya que podria afectar el rendimiento de la aplicacion

Comment: La desactive y el error persiste

Comment: podrias darle algo mas de formato a la pregunta, es solo un bloque de texto

Comment: añadí dos imagenes (si es a lo que te referías)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré el problema y se los comparto por si alguien mas se topa con el mismo problema: Resulta que mi programa se ejecuta sobre un formulario llamado `FrmPrincipal`, y al equivocarme en una variable de instancia de un `From` y no eliminar esa instancia (quería pasar datos de un `Form` a otro), debio generar un `bucle` (que no entiendo bien todavía porque) y Visual Studio no lo marcaba como un error ni advertencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: La aplicacion esta en desarrollo, por eso le faltan referencias a los handlers, entre otras muchas cosas, por eso me dejo de ejecutar al crear esa variable.
Si tienen algun consejo de mi error y/o idea de lo que pudo ser, es bienvenida.

Comment: Entonces esta es la solución al problema?

Comment: Para este caso si, si alguien mas se encuentra con el mismo error, puede desactivar la excepción del `ContextSwitchDeadlock`, que por lo que leí no es recomendable ya que puede afectar el rendimiento del programa (y en mi caso no funciono), o buscar una variable que este causando conflicto en el pasaje de mensajes en el programa, lo ideal es remontarse a las partes del programa donde se trabajo antes de que dejara de ejecutarse con normalidad.

Comment: Buena explicación, gracias por el aporte.. son de esos errores raros XD